# Java - Read files in a directory to a HashMap - recursive

Tags: java, recursion

Here below am trying to read fileNames from a nested folder structure into a hashmap,
Structure is like

```
Main Folder  
      -> EN (SubFolder1)  
             -> File1
             -> File2
      -> FR (SubFolder2)  
             -> File3
             -> File4
      -> GE (SubFolder3)  
             -> File5
             -> File6
```

HashMap contains "Sub FolderName" as Key & "FileNames"(ArrayList) as value.

I'm trying to make a recursive call & save things into HashMap, but missing something in that, things are not being saved into HashMap.

```
public static HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> listFilesForFolder(File folder)
        throws IOException {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> dirFiles = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    if(folder.isDirectory()) {
        ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
                dirFiles.put(folder.getName(), fileNames);
            } else {
                String fileName = (fileEntry.getPath()).toString();
                fileNames.add(fileEntry.getPath());
            }
        }
    }
    return dirFiles;
}
```

Please help me find out where am going wrong.

***Input is the path of the parent directory.***

Expected Output:

```
{"EN" = [File1, File2],  "FR" = [File3, File4], "GE" = [File5, File6]}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Why don't you use JSR 203?

Comment: What happens instead?  You get back an empty map?  Have you verified your `folder` is, in fact, a directory?  And that your `for` loop runs?  Try adding print statements to double check these assumptions.

Comment: @fge maybe they don't know about it... a link would be a good start.

Comment: More details about the problem at hand would be appreciated; for instance, are there only ever directories at the first level? Second, do you use Java 8, Java 7 or Java 6-? Third, why a Map as a return type?

Comment: Why is your method recursive? Your displayed structure is not: there is just one root folder, containing directories, containing files. There is no need for recursion here. Just read ell the folders from the root directory, and for each folder, read all the files from that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Folder {
    public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> dirFiles = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    public static void listFilesForFolder(File folder)
            throws IOException {

        if(folder.isDirectory()) {

            ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
               // System.out.println(fileEntry.toString());
                if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                //  System.out.println(fileEntry.toString());
                    listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
                } else {
                    String fileName = (fileEntry.getPath()).toString();
                    fileNames.add(fileEntry.getPath());
                }
            }
            dirFiles.put(folder.getName(), fileNames);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listFilesForFolder(new File("C:/Users/Guest/Documents/MainFolder"));
        for(Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> foldername : dirFiles.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(foldername.getKey() + " " + foldername.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

There are very minute changes need to be done in your code.

1. only when you loop through the entire list of files in
   folder.listFiles(), fileNames arraylist get populated with the names
   of files. Therefore I move the map put operation after the end of
   loop.
2. you are creating Map object for every iteration, though you are
   returning map object from the function which every recursive call
   will do. you have to process all the map objects together. Hence a
   global map object.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the JSR 203 API (which you should use for anything post 2011, provided you use Java 7+); the following code supposes Java 7+ (UNTESTED; but it should work):

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> listFiles(final Path baseDir)
    throws IOException
{
    final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    try (
        final DirectoryStream<Path> stream
            = Files.newDirectoryStream(baseDir);
    ) { 
        for (final Path subdir: stream)
            populateMap(map, subdir);
    }

    return ret;
}

private static void populateMap(final Map<String, List<String>> map,
    final Path subdir)
    throws IOException
{
    // .getFileName() returns the last component of the path...
    // REGARDLESS of whether that component is actually a "file"
    final String dirname = subdir.getFileName().toString();
    map.put(dirname, new ArrayList<>());
    try (
        final DirectoryStream<Path> stream
            = Files.newDirectoryStream(subdir);
    )
    {
        for (final Path entry: stream)
            map.get(dirname).add(entry.getFileName().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list of all directory and files under a directory use this:

```java
private List<String> filesPath = new ArrayList<>();

public void createDirectoryMap() {
    var storage = new File(path);
    if (storage.isDirectory()) {
        File[] children = storage.listFiles();
        if (children != null) {
            for (File childFile : children) {
                getAllDirectory(childFile);
            }
        }
    } else {
        filesPath.add(storage.getPath());
    }
    
    // Save your list

    filesPath.clear();
}

private void getAllDirectory(File file) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        File[] children = file.listFiles();
        if (children != null) {
            for (File childFile : children) {
                filesPath.add(childFile.getPath());
                getAllDirectory(childFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And output will somethings like this:

```
storage\private\60af64d4146f1e6e70bef903
storage\private\60af64d4146f1e6e70bef903\DSC_0171.jpg
storage\private\60af64d4146f1e6e70bef903\icon.jpg
storage\public\blog
storage\public\blog\61afe3d311771928ca98f5f3
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want your function to be recursive and keep the `Map` (although that's not the best choice), its definition should be :

```
Map<String,Map> listFilesForFolder(File folder);
```

I.e. the values of the map are map themselves or `null` meaning its a file.

---

This line has no effect if you don't use its result :

```
listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
```

Comment: Hi Gael, Thanks for your contribution. listFilesForFolder(fileEntry); is the main command which contributed to the whole function.